# Color Squares JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to use Jquery to make a series of colored squares within a given square area draggable but am struggling to contain the squares in the area.
So far I have this jquery code:

```
      square = $(square);
      square.draggable();
      squareArea = $(squareArea);
      squareArea.append(square);
```

which makes the squares draggable but disperses them over the entire page.

Would I need to convert my functions and commands from DOM to Jquery in order to contain the squares in my desired area?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the square inside the squareArea and set the containment property to "parent".

```
$("#blueSquare").draggable({
  containment: "parent"
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lot87hx6/

Comment: thanks for the response but it did not work. I'm working with multiple squares that are generated at random in my squareArea, the code you suggested only changes their position across the page.